# NestJS with TypeORM: How to connect a DB using TypeORM and make the instance accessible

Tags: javascript, typescript, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

Can anyone let me know how to create an instance of the DB using TypeORM?

I would like to make it accessible as this service does but the Connection class is deprecated..

```
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Connection, Repository } from 'typeorm';

@Injectable()
export class DatabaseService {
  constructor(@Inject('Connection') public connection: Connection) {
    console.log('!!!!')
  }
  public async getRepository<T>(entity: any): Promise<Repository<T>> {
    return this.connection.getRepository(entity);
  }
}
```

What is the alternative now?

How should I set up the DatabaseModule? In order to make it accessible? Using DataSource???

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      inject: [ConfigService],
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        type: 'postgres',
        host: process.env.DB_HOST,
        port: +configService.get('DB_PORT'),
        username: configService.get('DB_USER'),
        password: configService.get('DB_PASSWORD'),
        database: configService.get('DB_NAME'),
        autoLoadEntities: true,
        synchronize: true,
      })
    })
  ],
  providers: [DatabaseService]
})

export class DatabaseModule {}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you just trying to connect to the DB?  What are you planning to achieve? do you want multiple databases? the code above is calling mongoose which would be a mongo DB in the second picture you pointing to postgres?

Comment: I'm using Postgres but I would like to know how to expose the connection once that I have instantiated. I would like to follow the singleton as Nestjs provide so, how it could be to make that instance accessible?

Comment: Now is modified, sorry for the mistake I copied the wrong code..

Comment: Please see this article https://blog.devgenius.io/nestjs-use-a-solo-injectable-class-as-a-singleton-provider-884911eff279.     Hope it helps.   Instead of struggling you can also clone this repo and follow the pattern https://github.com/brocoders/nestjs-boilerplate

Answer (score 1):

Try to `@InjectDataSource()` instead of `@InjectConnection()`.

From [TypeORM documentation](https://typeorm.io/data-source#what-is-datasource):

> TypeORM's DataSource holds your database connection settings and
> establishes initial database connection or connection pool depend on
> RDBMS you use.

From the DataSource you'll be able to access everything you need: EntityManager, QueryRunner, EntityMetadata, repositories and other. [Here's the documentation](https://typeorm.io/data-source-api) for the DataSource API

Comment: Thank you Dinu, but how should I configure my DatabaseModule, I mean doing the forRootAsync I'm setting the options for the DB and it's returning the connection, isn't it? should I replace the foorRootAsync for new DataSource connection? Could you let me know how the code should look like?

Comment: You don't have to take care of the DataSource connection instance the NestJS Dependency Injection system does it for you. Once you've registered the TypeOrmModule (as in your example) NestJS will do everything needed behind to keep the instance of the connection active. If you want to access that connection just use the @InjectDataSource() decorator, to access that single instance.